# HTML Email not printing properly

Tags: php, html, email

I coded an HTML email that is intended to be sent via PHP to both a user for confirmation and a company address so we can print it for our records.  When I first started it would print everything fine including a 2nd page if the order was big enough, but now when I get a 2nd page, it only says there is one page and chops it off right in the middle of a div.  An older form I wrote prints two pages just fine so I don't think it's something wrong with my settings and I made sure and checked "print all pages" was selected.  I have tried this in both Thunderbird and Outlook as well as several email services with no success.

Could this be an issue with how the page is layout or a missing tag I may have overlooked?  I have included the email code as well.  It is heavy on inline styles due to gmails lack of support for external/internal stylesheets.  I have omitted some of the basic tags such as body and head purposefully.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="info" style="border: 1px black solid; border-radius: 20px; display: inline-block; font-family: Arial; font-weight:bold; color:black; width: 100%; padding: 0 7.5px;">
        <div class="left" style="float: left; clear: right; display: inline-block; font-size: 3em;">HD ' . ucfirst($_SESSION['sname']) . '</div>
        <div class="right" style="float: right; clear: right; display: inline-block; font-size: 3em;">' . $_SESSION['sdate'] .'</div>
        <div class="right" style="float: right; clear: left; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.53125em;">Placed by: ' . $_SESSION['name'] .'</div>
        <div class="left" style="float: left; clear: left; display: inline-block; font-size: 2.5em;">#' . $_SESSION['snumber'] . '</div>
        <div class="right" style="float: right; clear: right; display: inline-block; font-size: 1.53125em;">Pay by Scan</div>
    </div>

    <div class="instructions" style="border: 1px black solid; border-radius: 20px;">
        <div>Special Instructions: ' . $_SESSION['sinstruct'] .'</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="max-width: 612px; clear:both; font-size:12px; display: inline-block;">

    <div class="left" style="float: left; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px;border-radius: 20px;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">3.5" Herbs</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; margin-right:5px; text-align:left;">' . $herb1_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="float: right; margin-left:15px;">' . $herb1_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_1'] . '</div>

    </div>

    <div class="right" style="float: left; clear:right; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px;border-radius: 20px; display:inline;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">Qrt Herbs</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; margin-right:5px; text-align:left;">' . $herb2_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="float: right; margin-left:25px;">' . $herb2_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_2'] . '</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" style="max-width: 612px; clear:both; font-size:12px; display: inline-block;">

    <div class="left" style="float: left; clear: left; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px;border-radius: 20px;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">Pak Veggies</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; margin-right:5px; text-align:left;">' . $veg1_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="float: right; clear:right; margin-left:25px;">' . $veg1_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px; display: inline-block;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_3'] . '</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right" style="float: left; clear:right; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px; border-radius: 20px; display:inline;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">4" Veggies</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; margin-right:5px; text-align:left;">' . $veg2_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="float: right; margin-left:25px;">' . $veg2_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_4'] . '</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" style="max-width: 612px; clear:both; font-size:12px; display: inline-block;">

    <div class="left" style="float: left; clear: left; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px; border-radius: 20px;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">Gal Veggies</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; margin-right:5px; text-align:left;">' . $veg3_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="float: right; margin-left:25px;">' . $veg3_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_5'] . '</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right" style="float: left; clear:right; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px; border-radius: 20px; display:inline;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">Gal Herbs</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px; text-align:left;">' . $herb3_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="float: right; margin-left:25px;">' . $herb3_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_6'] . '</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" style="max-width:612px;clear:both; font-size:12px; display: inline-block;">

    <div class="left" style="float: left; clear: right; margin: 7.5px; padding:15px; border: 1px black solid; max-width: 300px; border-radius: 20px;">
        <h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left; clear: right;">2 Gal Veggies</h4><h4 style="padding:0; margin:0; top:0; right:25px; display:inline-block;float: right;">Qty</h4><br/>
        <div class="first" style="float: left; text-align:left;">' . $veg4_mail . '</div>
        <div class="second" style=" float: right; margin-left:25px;">' . $veg4_quant . '</div>
        <div class="second" style="clear: both; float: right; margin-left:15px;">Total: ' . $_SESSION['total_7'] . '</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Outlook (it may differ per client/OS), printing a page will break wherever it can. This is controlled by your printer/page setup. It will then break your email at the first spot it can find above the maximum page height.

It will probably pick a section between 2 tables, but the only way to force it not to break in a certain spot, is to use an image with height spanning over that section.